# Finding an index in a sorted array

Tags: arrays, performance, algorithm, big-o

Given a sorted array `A[1...n]` of keys, and another key, `x`, stored in `A`, show how to find the index, `k`, so that `A[k] = x` in time `O(log(k))`.

I know that a binary search on a sorted array would be completed in `O(logn)`, on average, but what would be the best way to show a run time of `O(logk)`, as described above, for a sorted array?
I appreciate any help.

Comment: Are your keys arbitrary values, or are they specifically integers?

Comment: I don't get the O(logk).. what does the k have to do with the O() complexity? k is just the value of the index, right? If that x is at index 0 should I complete it in O(log0) ?

Comment: @DavidKernin That's precisely what O(log k) is saying: Logarithmic in k, and hence (very slowly) growing as k grows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do an exponential search, starting with index m=1 then doubling m each time, until the array element at m is greater than x.  Then, do the normal binary search on the subset of the array below the final m.

Comment: Yep, something like this.

Comment: @user2580516 What is the reasoning behind doing an exponential search first?

Comment: @DerrekWhistle Independence from the total number of items. The exponential search gives you an upper bound for `k` that is off by at most a factor of 2, so you can do binary search on a range of length O(k) regardless of how much larger n might be.

Comment: @DerrekWhistle What delnan says.  Basically an O(log k) algorithm is only useful if the searches are almost always for an item very close to the beginning of the list.  The exponential search will limit the search space to the beginning of the list, avoiding a binary search of the whole list.  If you think about the case where the target item is almost always the first item in the list, this will make more sense, I think.

Comment: I see.  Thank you both for the explanations.

Answer (score 0):

Binary search giving O(log N) is the standard approach. I'm not sure if O(log k) is a misprint, a semi-equivalence, or suggests "biasing" the search towards the low end o the range.

Maybe a binary search using a non-halfway midpoint.. since differential of `log` is `log`, perhaps using `log()` function to choose a midpoint at each iteration?